# object property value as class name, ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Tried looking for an answer to this with no success.

Is there anyway to have the value of a property be the class name when using ng-class in angularJS?

An example of what I mean:

```
var things = [
        {
            a: "abc",
            aTrue: true
        }
];
```

Then in Angular (using ng-repeat in this instance)

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-class="{thing.a: !!thing.aTrue}></div>
```

I'm looking for the class name to be `"abc"` - but this gives me a class name of `"thing.a"`. Is this even possible, where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work is because it acts just like a Javascript object so you can't do this in javascript can you

```
var test = 'hello';

var object = {
    test: 'hi'
};

object[test] === undefined // true // or
object.hello === undefined // true 
object.test  === undefined // false
```

So you can't create a `key` with a variable like that. so try something like this.

```
 ng-class="{ true: thing.a, false: '' }[thing.aTrue]"
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XzXzR/1/**

what this does is this (explanation in javascript)

```
var test = {
   one: 'hello',
   two: 'world'
}['one'];
```

What does test equal?

```
test ===  Object {one: "hello", two: "world"} // false
test ===  Object {one: "hello"} // false
test ===  Object {two: "world"} // false
test === 'one'   // false
test === 'two'   // false
test === 'hello' // ** true **
test === 'world' // false
```